# Access Windows 10 C Drive

Tags: storage

Is there a way I can access my C drive? I am a Windows Phone developer and I need to transffer some files that are created on the Local State (In Windows 10 desktop, this would be in C:\Users(UserName)\AppData\Local\Packages(App ID)\LocalState). There is a trick online about using a Windows Desktop shortcut file as well as using the File Explorer URL bar to access C but none of these work on the latest version of Windows 10 Mobile.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) to access the isolated storage of apps that you've deployed to the connected device as a developer (so not apps that you've installed through the store)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Rowland Shaw said, it should be quite easy to just copy them programmatically to a folder that you can access (e.g. Music). I haven't tested this, but off the top of my head I think it would be something like:

```
await (await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("MyFileName")).CopyAsync(KnownFolders.MusicLibrary);
```